# What are all the options or features a DSLR camera body can have?

Tags: body, camera-design

I was curious to know if there was a place that lists all the options that are possible on a DSLR camera or even which cameras have them?

for example:
Video recording,
Night vision,
The speed in retaking a picture....
etc...

Comment: I don't think a site could list all _possible_ features, but an ambitious one could list all currently-existing features. :)

Comment: snapsort would be a start I guess, if you click into the Specifications detail.  I doubt any source is going to give you a really comprehensive list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Snapsort](http://snapsort.com/) is a great site that I think does what you're after. It's a really easy way to browse camera features and compare models side by side to decide what to buy.

Answer (score 3):

Well, [dpreview.com](http://www.dpreview.com/) has an extensive database. @Itai's [neocamera.com](http://www.neocamera.com/) is good as well.